# Sum of an array in row that says "Yes"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

=SUM(3, IF(B8:B129="Yes",1,0))

The formula should start on 3 and add 1 every time a column in the row says "Yes", Included in the row are "No" and "Maybe".

The current formula above provides the correct result however it outputs "#!VALUE" in the column.

Anybody know the issue with the formula?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the issue with a screenshot. It does seem that `=3+COUNTIF(B8:B129,"Yes")` should work.

Comment: Apologies Folks, Had to get rid of "SUM" stupid mistake. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of IF(B8:B129="Yes",1,0) you may want to use COUNTIF(B8:B129,”Yes”)

Comment: I have tried this and the error does disappear, However it doesn't count all the Yes' then it just takes the starting 3 and displays that. Bit of a tricky one!